# Swift encrypt the symmetric key itself

Tags: swift, encryption-symmetric

So we hace this security where we want to encrypt the AES generated Symmetric key itself.

Basically this flow:
Backend send us key -> we create a symmetric key -> we encrypt data with symmetric key -> we encrypt symmetric key with backend key -> we send everything back.

This is my attempt, but i expect something goes wrong here. But don't know what. Thanks in advance.

```
        guard let publicKeyData = Data(base64Encoded: publicKey) else {
            throw EncryptionError.invalidPublicKey
        }

        // Convert the recipient's public key data into a SecKey
        let keyAttributes: [CFString: Any] = [
            kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
            kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 2048 // Adjust key size as needed
        ]

        guard let key = SecKeyCreateWithData(publicKeyData as CFData, keyAttributes as CFDictionary, nil) else {
            throw EncryptionError.invalidPublicKey
        }

        // Convert the SymmetricKey to Data
        var secretKeyData = Data(count: secretKey.bitCount / 8)
        _ = secretKeyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { secretKeyDataBuffer in
                secretKey.withUnsafeBytes { secretKeyBuffer in
                    secretKeyDataBuffer.copyBytes(from: secretKeyBuffer)
                }
            }

        // Encrypt the symmetric key using the recipient's public key
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        guard let encryptedData = SecKeyCreateEncryptedData(
            key,
            .rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA1AESGCM,
            secretKeyData as CFData,
            &error
        ) else {
            if let error = error {
                throw error.takeRetainedValue()
            }
            throw EncryptionError.encryptionFailed
        }

        // Encode the encrypted symmetric key as base64 and return it
        return (encryptedData as Data).base64EncodedString()
    }
```

Edit:
This is how we encrypt the message:

````
        let iv = AES.GCM.Nonce()

        do {
            let sealedBox = try AES.GCM.seal(jsonData, using: secretKey, nonce: iv)
            let encryptedMessage = sealedBox.combined!
            return encryptedMessage.base64EncodedString()
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: "but i expect something goes wrong here. But don't know what" Anyone who might be able to solve this for you will probably need a lot more detail than that. What issues are you having? What trouble shooting steps have you tried? Without that kind of information, people will just be playing guessing games.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use CryptoKit. Is there a reason you're not?
Example:

```
import CryptoKit

guard let publicKeyData = Data(base64Encoded: publicKey) else {
        throw EncryptionError.invalidPublicKey
    }

    let key = Symmetric(size: .bits256)

// encrypt the keys data as extracted in your question.
    let encryptedContent = try ChaChaPoly.seal(publicKeyData, using: key).combined
    let sealedBox = try ChaChaPoly.SealedBox(combined: encryptedContent)
    
    let nonce = sealedBox.nonce
    let ciphertext = sealedBox.ciphertext
    let tag = sealedBox.tag
    
    assert(sealedBox.combined == nonce + ciphertext + tag)
    return sealedBox.combined
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know barely anything about encryption and just need to encrypt the secret key with the public key. Right now we are sealing the jsonData with a AES Symmetric key, but i guess that can change. Edited my post